# VHDL Use of variables vs signals inside a process

Tags: vhdl

I'm implementing the double dabble method (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dabble). Every cycle if a BCD(binary coded decimal) digit is > 4 then add 3 to it. Regardless of the addition there is a left shift, but the left shift is after the addition.

Because this seems too cumbersome to put in one statement I want to break it up. AFAIK breaking up a single statement should be done with a variable as I have done below, but I think a signal will also work as well. Is there a general guideline that says one is better than the other inside a process.

```
--this is a binary to BCD(binary coded decimal) converter
--it uses the double dabble algorithm from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dabble

--it takes a binary input of any length
--the length of the BCD is determined as 4*BCD_digits because every decimal digit in BCD takes 4 bits to encode
--it takes bin_len+1 cycles after go is asserted to convert
--first cycle pulls data, then the data is added and shifted bin_len times

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity binBCD is
    generic(
        bin_len : integer; --length of binary input
        BCD_digits : integer --number of decimal digits in BCD
    );
    port(
        clk  : in  std_logic;
        go   : in  std_logic; --pulse to start dd algorithm. if asserted while dd is running it will restart and the previous data will be lost
        done : out std_logic; --pulse to signinfy data is valid

        bin  : in  std_logic_vector(bin_len - 1 downto 0);
        BCD  : out std_logic_vector(BCD_digits*4 - 1 downto 0)
    );
end entity binBCD;

architecture RTL of binBCD is
    type reg_type is record
        bin : unsigned(bin_len - 1 downto 0);
        BCD : unsigned(BCD_digits*4 - 1 downto 0);
        count : integer range 0 to bin_len;
    end record;
    signal r, r_next : reg_type;
begin

    sequential : process(clk)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            r <= r_next;
            if go = '1' then --register inputs
                r.bin <= unsigned(bin);
                r.BCD <= (others => '0');
            elsif r_next.count = bin_len then --register outputs
                BCD <= std_logic_vector(r_next.BCD);
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

    combinational : process(r, go)
        variable add3 : unsigned(BCD_digits*4 downto 0);
    begin
        done <= '0';
        r_next.count <= r.count + 1;
        if go = '1' then
            r_next.count <= 1;
        elsif r.count = 0 then
            r_next.count <= 0; --count = 0 is waiting state (1 to bin_len is run)
        elsif r.count = bin_len then
            r_next.count <= 0;
            done <= '1';
        end if;


        --if any decimal (four bit piece of BCD) is greater than 4 add 3
        for i in BCD_digits - 1 downto 0 loop
            add3(i*4 + 3 downto i*4) := r.BCD(i*4 + 3 downto i*4);
            if unsigned(r.BCD(i*4 + 3 downto i*4)) > 4 then
                add3(i*4 + 3 downto i*4) := unsigned(r.BCD(i*4 + 3 downto i*4)) + 3;
            end if;
        end loop;

        --left shift the result of add3 (and msb of bin)
        r_next.BCD <= add3(BCD_digits*4 - 2 downto 0) & r.bin(bin_len - 1);

        --left shift bin (lsb doesn't matter, but i use '0')
        r_next.bin <= r.bin(bin_len - 2 downto 0) & '0';
    end process;

  end architecture RTL;
```

I'm specifically asking about the variable add3, but other comments are welcome.

Comment: It's hard to debug variables. Some simulators don't support variables to be dragged into the waveform. Variables can't be connected to integrated logic analyzers like ChipScope or SignalTap. The scope of variables is also restricted to processes unless it's a shared variable. I think you usage of `add3` is a good example where variables are useful :).

Comment: @Paebbels Variables *can* be connected to Chipscope. However, it depends on how you use it. I often use variable to describe register, and they show properly in Chipscope. They won't show if they don't directly translate to hardware, such as when used for intemediate, non-register, results.

Comment: One is not better than the other, they do different things. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13954193/is-process-in-vhdl-reentrant/13956532#13956532. My preference is for the single clocked process form, it avoids several difficulties with the combinational process. For example, using a variable in a combinational process, make sure you ALWAYS write it before reading, otherwise it infers storage. In a clocked process, this is a (safe) register, but in a combi process it's a latch, with difficult semantics, tangled up with the sensitivity list.

Comment: Also : for debugging variables on simulators that don't want to : it's trivial to copy their final values onto a signal for debugging.